# Get values from a dynamic drop-down list and show them in a dynamic text box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a table with dynamically generated rows, the first row is not dynamic and I want to show and print the values according to the choice made by the user from the dynamic dropdown list, I have jQuery and PHP code that only works in the first non-dynamic row and does not work in the rest of the new dynamic rows and I want to make the feature work In each new dynamic row that is generated, only the value associated with the user's selection appears (for example: the invoice system drop-down list contains the name of the product, and the price of the product appears in another text box when selecting any product from the drop-down list)

[The problem is shown in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qP8IQ.png)
php code:
`

```
<select class="form-control select_acount" name="account[]"required>
                            <option value="">--الحساب--</option>
                            <?php
                            $query = "select * from sah7atmain_acouts WHERE company like '".$multi."'";
                            $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                            $data = array();
                            if($result)
                            {
                              while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                              $data[] = $row;
                            ?>
                            <?php echo '<option value="'.$row['acount_mounte'].'">'.$row['acount_name'].'</option>'?>;
                            <?php
                            }
                            } else{
                            }
                            ?>
                            </select>
```

jquery code:

```
 $('.select_acount').on('change', function() {
   $(this).closest('tr').find('.mount').val($(this).val());
});
```

`Dynamic code generation using JaQuery"`

```
 var data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
      var product_dd = "";
          product_dd += '<select class="form-control select_acount" name="account[]"required>';
          product_dd += '<option value="">--الحساب--</option>';
      if(data.length > 0){
        for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i ++) {
          product_dd += `<option value="${data[i]['acount_mounte']}">${data[i]['acount_name']}</option>`;
        }
      }
         product_dd += "</select>";
      
      var i = 0;
      $("#add-btn").click(function() {
        ++i;
        
        $("#dynamicAddRemove").append('<tr><td class="td">'+product_dd+'</td> <td class="td"><input type="number" name="debtor[' + i + ']" id="fname"class="form-control debtor arabicNumbers" onkeydown="return event.keyCode !== 69" required></td> <td class="td"><input type="number" name="creditor[' + i + ']" id="james" class="form-control creditor arabicNumbers" onkeydown="return event.keyCode !== 69" required></td> <td class="td"><input type="text"  name="description[' + i + ']" class="form-control"  required></td> <td> <input type="text" name="mount[' + i + ']" class="form-control mount" required></td><td class="td2"><button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-danger remove-tr"><i class="fas fa-trash" ></i></button></td></tr>');
      });
      $(document).on('click', '.remove-tr', function() {
        $(this).parents('tr').remove();
      });
```

`

Comment: I really appreciate it my friend, it's working fine, I love you

Comment: Can I vote for you or support you with stars or something like that my friend, I am new to this platform and I do not know how to do that

Comment: Once you reach 15 reputation you can upvote answers.

Comment: All in all, thank you for helping me, and I owe you that

Comment: Do you have any specific question about all this code?

Comment: Also, be warned that your query is widely open for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Comment: @NicoHaase The question was related to the change event only firing on the first row as it existed when the page was loaded, but the dynamically added rows were not firing the event, this is why I provided the answer (was a comment) initially. Your point about sql injection is good advice.

Comment: Yes indeed. I have marked your answer as accepted  
@RyanWilson

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery, I would recommend using a delegated event handler approach and add your event to the table/container element of your dynamic rows, so your event listener declaration would look like this:

```
$('#dynamicAddRemove').on('change', '.select_acount', function() {    
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.mount').val($(this).val()); 
});
```

This way your event will fire for every newly added row. More information on event delegation: [jQuery-event-delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)